# Can't upload media to my Raspberry Pi Wordpress server

Tags: linux

Thanks in advance for any useful tips. I'll cut to the chase.

I followed these guides to set up my wordpress server:
1 - https://www.techcoil.com/blog/setting-up-wordpress-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-raspbian-stretch-lite-nginx-mariadb-and-php-7-as-the-lemp-stack/
2 - https://www.stewright.me/2014/06/tutorial-install-wordpress-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-nginx/ *(referred the section titled "Set some permissions" only, otherwise all done with first tutorial)*

Uploading media still didn't work, so I performed the following in the `www` folder to try and cover all bases:

`sudo chmod -R 777 .`

Yet still, when I try to upload media in Wordpress, it says:
*"filename.jpg

HTTP error"*

What am I missing? About me: Not an expert in this stuff clearly, but can get the concepts pretty quickly with some explanation. Thank you!!

Comment: Forgot to mention, running Raspi 3 + Raspbian Stretch, and using my own IP address through NoIP as my "DNS service". Site runs fine with a new WP install, blog posts, etc. Just can't upload media/plugins from my laptop in the wp interface.

Comment: Oh god, it was because the file was too big, even though it was less than the 2MB size limit stated in WP. I tried a 1.4MB file that wasn't working work, but a 400KB file worked. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the owner of the wordpress folder to www-data.

For example, if you put your wordpress folder in /var/www/my_new_wordpress_site, you will need to run the following command:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/my_new_wordpress_site`

Comment: No luck :( Still says HTTP error. Tried it in the parent folder as well and did a reboot to be sure.